# Convert image to another format

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to convert a `png` image to `jpg` using `Angular 4+`. Is there an easy way to do this?

I have looked for different libaries, but I only found libraries for manipulating images.

Comment: It would be much easier to do this sever side. Perhaps using a php script that you post to

Comment: not sure but there might be a third party api you can send your image to for conversion using angular

Comment: http://processingjs.org/

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._